# Combine multiple rows with duplicate id

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is `odb.OPMdata`

`columns  = id, element, budget, month`

i want it todo is

this sample sql query is not displaying all row with `Id='1'` only the MAX and MIN of it.

```
SELECT month, MAX(budgetmonth) AS value1, MAX(actual) AS value2, MAX(variance) AS value3,
       MIN(budgetmonth) AS value4, MIN(actual) AS value5, MIN(variance) AS value6
FROM OPMdata
GROUP BY month
```

my problem is how to join the three or more duplicate rows to a single row, and the value will be display in each column.

i want to achieved is this.

```
id | value1 | value2 | value3  | value4 |value5| value 6 | value7 | value8 |val9 

1  |  CC    |  100   | january |  FF    |  100 |february |  DD    |  200   |mar
```

and so on for other rows with the same id.
please help on this and thanks in advance.

Comment: How many possible duplicates is there?

Comment: Please, add sample of data from `OPMdata` table.

Comment: @sagi the duplicates might be 12 for each id,

Comment: So you want 36 columns ?

Comment: @gofr1 sample is from OPMdata table is example table.
id | element  | budget | month  |
1  | CC       | 100    |january |
1  | FF       | 100    |february|
1  | DD       | 200    |march   |
2  | SS       | 150    |jun     |

Comment: @sagi yes. this can be done?

Comment: Yes, google - `SQL-Server pivot multiple columns` , you will have plenty of answers

Comment: Hi @sagi, can you help me with this im new to sql. that's why i have a bit of knowledge of it.

Comment: Why there will be duplicate ... your are selecting month and the rest is 1 value functions Min / Max

Comment: where are these columns coming from `actual` , `budgetmonth`, `variance` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try triple join like this + month table to order things right:

```
;WITH months AS ( -- Table with months for ordering
SELECT DATENAME(month,'1970-01-01') as [month], 1 as [level]
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(month,DATEADD(month,[level],'1970-01-01')), [Level]+1
FROM months
WHERE [level] < 12
)
, results AS ( --Temp cte with add of ROW_NUMBERS()
SELECT  id, 
        element, 
        budget, 
        o.[month],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY m.[level]) as rn
FROM OPMdata o
LEFT JOIN months m
    ON m.[month] = o.[month]
)
--Final query:
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
        r.id,
        r.element,
        r.budget,
        r.[month],
        r1.element,
        r1.budget,
        r1.[month],
        r2.element,
        r2.budget,
        r2.[month]
FROM results r
LEFT JOIN results r1
    ON r.id = r1.id and r.rn = r1.rn-1
LEFT JOIN results r2
    ON r1.id = r2.id and r1.rn = r2.rn-1
ORDER BY r.rn
```

Output:

```
id  element budget  month   element budget  month       element budget  month
1   CC      100     january FF      100     february    DD      200     march
2   SS      150     june    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to create view you can use this query:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewNameHere
AS
    WITH months AS ( -- Table with months for ordering
    SELECT DATENAME(month,'1970-01-01') as [month], 1 as [level]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATENAME(month,DATEADD(month,[level],'1970-01-01')), [Level]+1
    FROM months
    WHERE [level] < 12
    )
    , results AS ( --Temp cte with add of ROW_NUMBERS()
    SELECT  id, 
            element, 
            budget, 
            o.[month],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY m.[level]) as rn
    FROM OPMdata o
    LEFT JOIN months m
        ON m.[month] = o.[month]
    )
    --Final query:
    --every column with unique name 'value*'
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
            r.id        as value1,
            r.element   as value2,
            r.budget    as value3,
            r.[month]   as value4,
            r1.element  as value5,
            r1.budget   as value6,
            r1.[month]  as value7,
            r2.element  as value8,
            r2.budget   as value9,
            r2.[month]  as value10,
    FROM results r
    LEFT JOIN results r1
        ON r.id = r1.id and r.rn = r1.rn-1
    LEFT JOIN results r2
        ON r1.id = r2.id and r1.rn = r2.rn-1
    ORDER BY r.rn
```

Comment: Hi, @gofr1 i've tested it and its works. thanks you for your excellent query

Comment: i run your query using sql studion it give's me an error. here's the error:  SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.

Comment: I suppose you are trying to create a view. Am I right?

Comment: yes @gofr1, cause i need to put in ASP and bind it to gridview

Comment: You must name every column with unique name at first. When using cte SSMS can not show panes, you must ignore this warning, the view will be created anyway.

Comment: i'll give it a shot @gofr

Comment: I add a create view script to my answer.